# Firebase: How to recognize the first signup using an authentication provider

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

thanks for coming,

I am implementing Firebase authentication with Facebook and Twitter, I have a special need after the first registration in the user. We are creating a referal system and I need to keep a token and know if it is the first to log in to add points to the user that  refers him.

I can easy separate both methods with email and password but i cannot do it with social provider.

```
signInRegular(email, password) {
    const credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
}


emailSignUp(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(user => {
      this.userDetails = user;
      console.log(this.userDetails);
    }).catch(error => error);
}
```

The problem I have is that Firebase brings a unique method to log in and register.

```
signInWithFacebook() {
  this.auth.signInWithFacebook().then((res) => {
    console.log("Authenticated with Facebook")
  }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

I am planning to do it through the database and store if the users have a created account or not.

however, I would like to find a way to avoid making a query to the database

If you hace any suggestion or interest, everything is appreciated!

Hands up

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48982151/firebase-auth-check-if-new-user-on-facebook-login Firebase returns a flag whether the user is new or existing.

Comment: @bojeil Thanks so much!!! this is absolutely the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @bojeil he found this post

[Stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48982454/6448362)

Firebase auth did provide an indicator telling if the user is new or not.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error.
  });
```

This is the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#.AdditionalUserInfo) that refers to this feature.

Answer (score 1):

You must either keep a record of the referral in your database/data store. Pass a unique key to the referer who will then pass it to the new user. Add a referral key input to your new user signup flow to collect the referral key.

As part of recording new users in your data store, query the `referralKeys` collection for a matching key (which will have the uid of the original referrer as a property)